# React Native - SetTimeout() is not working. t.apply is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to play back audio after a delay of time

```
_onPlayPausePressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.sound.pauseAsync();
      } else {
        setTimeout(this.sound.playAsync(), 2000);
      }
    }
  };
```

However it returns error: t.apply is not a function. (In't.apply(void 0,o)','t.apply' is undefined)
I tried the updated method of Oleg. It worked the first time but it won't run again after that. Here are more insight of my code:

```
//import the array with sound details:{id, name desc, sound}
import { soundArray } from "./CreateRecord";
...
export default class CurrentRecord extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.currentSound = [];
    this.recording = null;
    this.sound = null;
    this.isSeeking = false;
    this.shouldPlayAtEndOfSeek = false;
    this.state = {
      haveRecordingPermissions: false,
      isLoading: false,
      isPlaybackAllowed: false,
      muted: false,
      soundPosition: null,
      soundDuration: null,
      recordingDuration: null,
      shouldPlay: false,
      isPlaying: false,
      isRecording: false,
      fontLoaded: false,
      shouldCorrectPitch: true,
      volume: 1.0,
      rate: 1.0,
      isModalVisible: false
    };
    this.recordingSettings = JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_LOW_QUALITY)
    );
  }

//load the audio when the component mount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAudio();

    (async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        "cutive-mono-regular": require("../../assets/fonts/CutiveMono-Regular.ttf")
      });
      this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    })();
    this._askForPermissions();
  }

//load the sound
  async loadAudio() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const id = navigation.getParam("id");
    this.sound = new Audio.Sound();
    for (let i = 0; i < soundArray.length; i++) {
      if (soundArray[i].id === id) {
        this.currentSound = soundArray[i];
        console.log(this.currentSound);

        break;
      }
    }
    try {
      await this.sound.loadAsync({
        uri: this.currentSound.sound /* url for your audio file */
      });
      await this.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(
        this._updateScreenForSoundStatus
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR Loading Audio", e);
    }
  }

//change screen based on the status
  _updateScreenForSoundStatus = status => {
    if (status.isLoaded) {
      this.setState({
        soundDuration: status.durationMillis,
        soundPosition: status.positionMillis,
        shouldPlay: status.shouldPlay,
        isPlaying: status.isPlaying,
        rate: status.rate,
        muted: status.isMuted,
        volume: status.volume,
        shouldCorrectPitch: status.shouldCorrectPitch,
        isPlaybackAllowed: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        soundDuration: null,
        soundPosition: null,
        isPlaybackAllowed: false
      });
      if (status.error) {
        console.log(`FATAL PLAYER ERROR: ${status.error}`);
      }
    }
  };

  _askForPermissions = async () => {
    const response = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
    this.setState({
      haveRecordingPermissions: response.status === "granted"
    });
  };

//here's where i want to delay the audio file. 
  _onPlayPausePressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.sound.pauseAsync();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => this.sound.playAsync(), 2000);
      }
    }
  };

  _onStopPressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      this.sound.stopAsync();
    }
  };

  _onMutePressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      this.sound.setIsMutedAsync(!this.state.muted);
    }
  };

  _onVolumeSliderValueChange = value => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      this.sound.setVolumeAsync(value);
    }
  };

  _trySetRate = async (rate, shouldCorrectPitch) => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      try {
        await this.sound.setRateAsync(rate, shouldCorrectPitch);
      } catch (error) {
        // Rate changing could not be performed, possibly because the client's Android API is too old.
      }
    }
  };

  _onRateSliderSlidingComplete = async value => {
    this._trySetRate(value * RATE_SCALE, this.state.shouldCorrectPitch);
  };

  _onPitchCorrectionPressed = async value => {
    this._trySetRate(this.state.rate, !this.state.shouldCorrectPitch);
  };

  _onSeekSliderValueChange = value => {
    if (this.sound != null && !this.isSeeking) {
      this.isSeeking = true;
      this.shouldPlayAtEndOfSeek = this.state.shouldPlay;
      this.sound.pauseAsync();
    }
  };

  _onSeekSliderSlidingComplete = async value => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      this.isSeeking = false;
      const seekPosition = value * this.state.soundDuration;
      if (this.shouldPlayAtEndOfSeek) {
        this.sound.playFromPositionAsync(seekPosition);
      } else {
        this.sound.setPositionAsync(seekPosition);
      }
    }
  };

  _getSeekSliderPosition() {
    if (
      this.sound != null &&
      this.state.soundPosition != null &&
      this.state.soundDuration != null
    ) {
      return this.state.soundPosition / this.state.soundDuration;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  _getMMSSFromMillis(millis) {
    const totalSeconds = millis / 1000;
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);

    const padWithZero = number => {
      const string = number.toString();
      if (number < 10) {
        return "0" + string;
      }
      return string;
    };
    return padWithZero(minutes) + ":" + padWithZero(seconds);
  }

  _getPlaybackTimestamp() {
    if (
      this.sound != null &&
      this.state.soundPosition != null &&
      this.state.soundDuration != null
    ) {
      return `${this._getMMSSFromMillis(
        this.state.soundPosition
      )} / ${this._getMMSSFromMillis(this.state.soundDuration)}`;
    }
    return "";
  }

  _getRecordingTimestamp() {
    if (this.state.recordingDuration != null) {
      return `${this._getMMSSFromMillis(this.state.recordingDuration)}`;
    }
    return `${this._getMMSSFromMillis(0)}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
_onPlayPausePressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.isPlaying) {
       this.sound.pauseAsync();
          } else {
         setTimeout(()=>this.sound.playAsync(), 2000);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it. However the sound won't be able to be played play anymore.

Comment: Updated the answer, please try again, if will not work post more code.

Comment: It only run the first time and it won't run again after that. I just post some extra codes below

Comment: Where did you update the state  of this.state.isPlaying? Put some logs in your code or post the expo snack.

Comment: I think that's where i was wrong. When i created the sound file in another tab. I did the same thing but it worked perfectly fine. I don't know why it's like that. Do you have suggestion on where should i update it?

Comment: https://github.com/WilliamP1998/Audio-Recorder_App I attempted to upload on expo snack but it failed so here's my repository for the code if you need to run it. The instruction on how to run it is listed in detail in readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

Remove execution of function. Also use arrow function(()=> {}) in playAsync

```
_onPlayPausePressed = async () => {
  if (this.sound != null) {
    if (this.state.isPlaying) {
      await this.sound.pauseAsync();
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        await this.sound.playAsync()
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, if i do that the play button won't run anymore

Comment: playAsync() is expo function for play the audio

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/ you can look up more into it in here

Comment: @minhphạm pls try fix